# Proving the Existence of n-linked knots

Tags: general-topology, topological-groups, knot-theory, knot-invariants

I was reading up on knots and links and came across:

The Hopf Link:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopf_link

Solomon's Knot (Double Link):
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solomon%27s_knot

Which got me wondering if there was some clever way that two unknots could be triply linked.

I started playing around and found a way to construct one. I conjecture general it is possible to construct an n-linked Knot using just two unknots, but I don't know how to show this.

One Idea I had was consider the sequence U for under, O for over

Then if $$ \underbrace{{(U O) (U O)  ... (U O)}}_{\text{n times}} $$  is the pattern of one line linking over another unknot, with that line finally fused at the end, I believe this is an inseperable link of n over crossings.

But I have no idea how to rigorously make it clear that its not seperable. For that matter I don't know how to even rigorously define what seperable even means without some ridiculous definition such as, there is no sequence shifting, and twisting (where I give explicit mathematical transformations for each in the form of a general functional) that could allow the number of overcrossings to fall below n or increase over n.

I also have to now have a means of counting over crossings using continuous functions which I'm not sure how to do.

Comment: Are you looking for this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linking_number ?

Comment: I believe the knots you are describing are $2,2n$ torus links.  There is a lot of information about them around.

Comment: @LukasGeyer indeed it seems they are